# mongoimport is not working in mac

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to import json file using mongoimport utility. But it is not working.
I have set the Envirnonment variable in ~/.bashrc file.

In ~/.bashrc file, I have given:
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/rakesh/Downloads/mongo`

Where mongo is directory, which includes all mongodb bin files like mongo, mongod, mongodump, mongoimport etc.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

the path isn't properly defined. Point to bin folder:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/rakesh/Downloads/mongo/bin`